# ElasticSearch Custom Script for Ordering Performance

Tags: groovy, elasticsearch

I wrote a simple scoring based on a document parameter like below:

```
POST /_scripts/groovy/CustomScoring
{
 "script": "(_source.ProductHits==null ? 0.1 :
    (_source.ProductHits[myval]==null?0.2:_source.ProductHits[myval]))"
}
```

When I use this custom script to sort search results like this:

```
POST /ecs/product/_search
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [
           {
               "function_score":{
                    "query" : {"match_all": {}}
                    ,"script_score": {
                        "script_id": "CustomScoring",
                        "lang" : "groovy",
                        "params":{
                            "myval": "iphone"
                        }
                    }
                }
           }
        ]
    }
  }
}
```

It takes *800ms* to run on 50'000 documents (vs initial run-time which was around *1ms*).
How can I optimize this groovy function?
Can Elasticsearch use some kind of caching for this function?

p.s. When I tried to use sum complex formulas based on doc.some_param.value and embedded functions like log it took *40ms* instead which is still reasonable.

Comment: my guess here would be, that from a groovy point of view, there is hardy anything to optimize, that would make me expect to get your performance from 800ms down to 40ms.  have you tried to benchmark, what is happening, if you remove the digging into the map in steps (from right)?

Comment: Why dont you use doc instead of _source .... _source needs to be fetched from disk , deserialized and then served. Which will obviously take lots of time. doc is something that is memory resident and a lot faster

Comment: @Vineeth-Mohan The problem is when I want to add some parameters like keywords(e.g. if a "iphone" is search for fifth time, then the value of it is set like: "iphone": 5) each time search is invoked and then sort them based on invocation times, as a simple machine learning algorithm.